I get an error [Object object] when I'm trying to export excel file
when iam trying to export excel file it is not export perfectly it shows this object error.
error](https://i.sstatic.net/pzXSMjcf.png)
so it is not passing the categoryId. can you help me to find a solusion to this issue?
this is js code related to this part. file have more other codes also so thats why i give this part only.
const [cropCategoryList, setCropCategoryList] = useState([]);
  const [seasons, setSeasons] = useState([]);
  const [selectedSeason, setSelectedSeason] = useState(null);
  const [toggleState, setToggleState] = useState(1);
  const [selectedWeek, setSelectedWeek] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    get_CategoryList().then(({ dataList = [] }) => {
      setCropCategoryList(dataList);
    });

    getSeasons().then(({ dataList = [] }) => {
      setSeasons(dataList);
    });
  }, []);

  const toggleTab = (index) => {
    console.log("toggle state : " + index);
    setToggleState(index);
  };
  const { addSnackBar } = useSnackBars();

  const onDownloadSuccess = () => {
    addSnackBar({
      type: SnackBarTypes.success,
      message: "Downloaded successfully",
    });
  };
  const onDownloadError = () => {
    addSnackBar({
      type: SnackBarTypes.error,
      message: "Download failed",
    });
  };
  const onDownload = async (categoryId) => {
    try {
      await downloadNationalExcel(
        selectedSeason.id,
        categoryId,
        selectedWeek.id
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };


export const downloadNationalExcel = async (
  seasonId,
  categoryId,
  weekId,
  onSuccess = () => {},
  onError = (_message) => {}
) => {
  try {
    const url =  `crop-/report/nationl/category/${categoryId}/season/${seasonId}/week/${weekId}/export/excel`;
    const blobData = await getBlobData(url);
    const fileName = `National_report_(${new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0]}.xlsx`;
    downloadFile(blobData, fileName);
    onSuccess();
  } catch (error) {
    handleError(error, onError);
  }
};

i want to pass correctly the categoryId.

You haven't shown the part that calls onDownload so pretty much impossible to tell why the parameter is not what you expect.
